# How to remove a particular set of cells from a cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell

Suppose I have an array with 10 cells: `C{1},C{2},...,C{10}`, and let `b=[1 2 8]`, then I want to empty `C{1}`, `C{2}` and `C{8}`, so I tried `C{b}=[]`, but it does't work. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: So you mean `b=[1 2 8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C(b) = []` will do it. The `{}` notation is for addressing the contents of a cell rather than the cell as a member of the array. If you get more than one cell back from the `{}` notation it returns as a comma separated list which you can't use for indexing. The `()` notation will get you an index to the actual cells themselves and is thus the correct way to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much, another question, when I use C(b) = [], I found the dimension of C reduced to 7, If I when to keep the dimension still is 10, how to do it?

Comment: One way would be like this: `c(b) = {[]}`

Comment: Thanks again, you give me a great help!